# Where's Lamedh in Gboard's Hebrew Keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, gboard

I'm trying to type Hebrew into Duolingo on the Android app, and I'm mostly able to use the Gboard keyboard.

However, it appears to be missing the letter [Lamedh](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamedh).

Here's a sample screencap of the keyboard in use:

[image]

Now, I don't speak Hebrew, and I'm new to Gboard, but am I correct in that this letter isn't present?

It's preventing me from typing many common Hebrew words, so I'm guessing I'm missing something. Is it there but in a font or style I'm just not seeing?

Answer (score 2):

I don't speak Hebrew. However, the character you are looking for is not missing from Gboard Hebrew keyboard.

It's located on the 2nd row, 3rd character from the right. This is the result after pressing it: `ל`.